# class based view passing parameters

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have just started using Class-based views and I am trying to pass the parameters to class-based view as:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myView'), kwargs={'method': 'learning'})
```

My view is:

```
class MyView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'algoRunning.html' 

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print (kwargs['method'])
        data = self.readFile('myFile.txt')
        context = {'result': data}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def readFile(self, filePath):
        # read data
        return data
```

my url pattern looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [...    
url(r'^learning/(?P<method>[a-z]+)/$', my_views.MyView.as_view(), name='myView'),
..]
```

But, it gives me following error

```
Reverse for 'myView' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['learning/(?P<method>[a-z]+)/$']
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the parentheses in the wrong place. `kwargs` is a parameter to `reverse`, not to `HttpResponseRedirect`.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myView', kwargs={'method': 'learning'}))
```

Note, this could be shortened by using the `redirect` shortcut:

```
return redirect('myView', method='learning')
```

Comment: Facepalm!! Thanks for a quick response

Answer (score 2):

`kwargs` should be reverse function's argument:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myView', kwargs={'method': 'learning'}))
```